# Codename One : AutoCompleteTextField refresh list on textfield text change

Tags: java, codenameone, google-geocoding-api

I try with Codename One to do a field text autocomplete with Google Maps Geocoding API.
I do the [GoogleReverseGeocoderService](http://www.codenameone.com/expression-language-for-json-and-xml.html) class like [here](http://www.codenameone.com/expression-language-for-json-and-xml.html) , I change "public GoogleReverseGeocoderService(double latitude, double longitude)" to "public GoogleReverseGeocoderService(String address)". And it works well.

So I override getSuggestionModel() and filter() like bellow code, i create a variable DefaultListModel model1, with "model1.addItem("Example");" because i don't know why if i don't add item, the new list added doesn't display.

I add addDataChangeListener to the AutoCompleteTextField variable "lieu", in the function dataChanged, i get the text entered by user in the field and send to google geocoding search. I get each "formatted_address" found and put in the model list **model1**, so the list of AutoCompleteTextField is changed.

But I have 3 problems:

1/ How to set the size of items displayed in AutoCompleteTextField, because i have 2 displayed items if I add one time **model1.addItem("Example")** and 4 rows if I add 2 **model1.addItem("Example");**, it multiplies by two, and so on...

```
           @Override
        public ListModel<String> getSuggestionModel() {
            model1.addItem("Example");

            filter = new FilterProxyListModel<String>(model1);
            return filter;
        }
```

[image]

2/ GoogleReverseGeocoderService doesn't accept the accendted characters entered by user, like "élé", i must tape "ele" to have som result. How i can encoded the request ?

3/ The list displayed from AutoCompleTextField doesn't refresh sometimes,i must press on it with mouse. But maybe because of simulator ?

> Louis I Ave, Marrero, LA 70072, USA
>   St Louis, MO, USA
>   Louisiana Blvd NE, Albuquerque, NM, USA
>   W Louisiana Ave, Soperton, GA 30457, USA
>   Louisiana Ave S, Minnesota, USA
>   W Louisiana St, McKinney, TX 75069, USA
>   S Louisiana St, Ida, LA 71044, USA
>   N Louisiana St, Ida, LA 71044, USA
>   Louis I Ave, Marrero, LA 70072, USA
>   St Louis, MO, USA
>   Louisiana Blvd NE, Albuquerque, NM, USA
>   W Louisiana Ave, Soperton, GA 30457, USA
>   Louisiana Ave S, Minnesota, USA
>   W Louisiana St, McKinney, TX 75069, USA
>   S Louisiana St, Ida, LA 71044, USA
>   N Louisiana St, Ida, LA 71044, USA

Here the all code :

```
    // Define in class
    protected FilterProxyListModel<String> filter;
    protected DefaultListModel model1 = new DefaultListModel();
    [ .... ]

    //Code for google autocomplete
    String locationText = "";
    final AutoCompleteTextField lieu = new AutoCompleteTextField(){

        private FilterProxyListModel<String> filter;

        @Override
        public ListModel<String> getSuggestionModel() {
            model1.addItem("Example");
            model1.addItem("Example");
            model1.addItem("Example");
            model1.addItem("Example");
            model1.addItem("Example");
            model1.addItem("Example");
            model1.addItem("Example");

            filter = new FilterProxyListModel<String>(model1);
            return filter;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean filter(String text) {
            if(filter != null) {
                filter.filter(text);        
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    lieu.setHint("Add address ...");
    lieu.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {
        public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {

            try {
                Location l = Display.getInstance().getLocationManager().getCurrentLocation();
                ConnectionRequest request = new GoogleReverseGeocoderService("" + lieu.getText()) {
                        @Override
                      protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                            Result result = Result.fromContent(input, Result.JSON);
                            array = result.getAsStringArray("//formatted_address");
                            model1.removeAll(); // Remove all elements in list, before insert news
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                                System.out.println(""+array[i]);
                                model1.addItem(array[i]);
                            }
                       }
                };
                NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request); 
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });      
    addComponent(lieu);
```

Hope i ame clear, Someone has an idea?

Thanks you,
Bye

Comment: I read this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/codenameone-discussions/hRHzjrjnWM8/t5XTmIONLVcJ
But it doesn't work

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly doesn't work? Is it the auto-complete or the geocoding? Did you open this in the debugger and check the values?

Comment: Hi Shai, i edited my question :)

Comment: The link to the reverse geocoder service is wrong so its harder for me to help as I'm not very familiar with that API. There are really 3 separate questions here so it would have helped to split it up.

Answer (score 0):

The code above uses the data changed listener to do the filtering and it shouldn't do that since that's too late for the filter to adapt the model size.

You should do that within the `filter` method itself since that is the place where the filtering should occur and that's where the list dialog size will be enlarged. When you modify the model manually the size of the entire list isn't adapted.

For encoding to work correctly you should use the version of result that accepts a Reader with the right encoding (probably UTF-8) to get that to work.